# 603 -ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error ORA-00600:

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle DB which is in W28MSWIN1252  and using the Oracle DMU (Data Migration Assistant tool for Unicode) I'm trying to convert the encoding to to ALT32UTF8. I successfully passed the scanning, but the next step - the actual database conversion, stops on this operation(the table and column names are changes):

```
update  /*+ PARALLEL(A,4)*/ "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE1" A  set A."COL1" = SYS_OP_CSCONV(A."COL1", 'AL32UTF8'), A."COL2" = SYS_OP_CSCONV(A."COL2", 'AL32UTF8'), A."COL3" = SYS_OP_CSCONV(A."COL3", 'AL32UTF8'), A."COL4" = SYS_OP_CSCONV(A."COL4", 'AL32UTF8') WHERE A.ROWID IN (SELECT ROW_ID FROM SYSTEM.DUM$EXCEPTIONS WHERE OBJ# = 93203)
```

with this error:

```
603 - ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error ORA-00600: Internal error code, arguments:[4882], [0x7FF7A52EEDB8],[0x7FF7A5A6D6B8], [0x7FF7C05ABB8],[],[],[]..
```

I Found an additional more info about the error in 
C:\app\Oracle12\diag\rdbms...\trace\alert_ax12web.log:

```
    Refresh failed due to missing on - commit privilege for               "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE2"
    On commit
    MV "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE2" was not refreshed successfully.
    Number of MV refresh failures : 1.
    Errors in file C:\app\Oracle12\diag\rdbms\...\trace\ax12web_ora_6672.trc(incident = 12425) :
    ORA - 00600 : internal error code, arguments : [4882], [0x7FF7B71BA8B8], [0x7FF7A5A6D6B8], [0x7FF7BFFA1D48], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
    ...
```

It seems that the real problem is : **Refresh failed due to missing on - commit privilege for something**. Unfortunately granting all privileges to everyone on this table via:

```
   grant ALL on "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE1" to public;
```

doesn't help. I still get this error.

P.S. I don't have additional support from oracle :(.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Kalin

Comment: That is an oracle internal issue, and you need to open an SR with oracle support.

Answer (score 1):

ORA-00600 means it's an internal error. You need to check the database alert.log or Oracle Support for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-running the query with small changes.  ORA-600 bugs usually only affect one specific way of running a query and there's usually a work-around.  Here are some ideas:

1. Remove the parallel hint.  If you can't control the query text then you can still get the same result by temporarily running `alter system set parallel_max_servers=0;`.
2. Run `(SELECT ROW_ID FROM SYSTEM.DUM$EXCEPTIONS WHERE OBJ# = 93203)` separately and hard-code the results into the query.
3. Break the statement up and only update one column at a time.

For ORA-600 errors there is a special tool for looking up the codes.  On support.oracle.com, search for "ora-600 tool".  On that website, enter the first argument.  It returns one result, *ORA-600 [4882] "Lock row cache object X when already held" (Doc ID 41840.1)*.

I can't print the whole document here, you need a license to get all that information.  But in this case it doesn't matter because there is no useful information.  Your choices are to either submit a Service Request and go through that painful process or try some of the rewrites suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after few days of reading logs and wild guesses I think I found the problem:

```
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW MYTABLE2;
```

After that the error disappears. And of course after the migration I had to recreate that view. Obviously this is a bug in Oracle. But what disgusts me is the Price model of the Oracle. They have a bug, but you must pay to get it fixed or to get a workaround.

... I have no idea how this could be related to the permissions